# Not able to access google cloud bucket file from local

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am running a spark scala job in local environment and trying to read a file from GCS bucket but facing an authorization issue.

```
"code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "The project to be billed is associated with an absent billing account.",
    "reason" : "accountDisabled"
```

I have authenticate and set the project from my IntelliJ terminal

```
gcloud config set account vikrant.singh@xyx.com
gcloud config set project my-test-project
```

My id 'vikrant.singh@xyx.com' has `storageadmin` role access on IAM page.
using same terminal I am able to list down the bucket information

```
gsutil ls -l gs://my-test-bucket/spark-job-configs
```

Here's my code:

```
package com.vikrant.test
import com.google.cloud.storage.{BlobId, StorageOptions}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object ReadBucketFileData {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {


    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("spark-bigquery-demo")
      .config("spark.master", "local")
      .getOrCreate()

    
    val storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance.getService
    val my_blob = storage.get(BlobId.of("bucket_name", "gs://my-test-bucket/spark-job-configs/my_test.yml"))
    println("my_blob:"+my_blob)

    spark.stop()
  }

  }
```

here's my `build.sbt:`

```
name := "MyTestProject"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val sparkVersion = "2.4.3"
  Seq( "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion)
  Seq( "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion)
}

libraryDependencies += "com.google.cloud.spark" %% "spark-bigquery-with-dependencies" % "0.16.1"

libraryDependencies += "net.jcazevedo" %% "moultingyaml" % "0.4.2"
libraryDependencies += "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "3.4.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.google.cloud" % "google-cloud-storage" % "1.23.0"
```

Comment: Is this project associated with billing account?
I think you need to list your billing accounts and link the project with an existing billing account. Looks like it is not already linked to the billing account.